# NSArray of string numbers representing NSDates grab only number closest to current date but ignoring todays date

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsarray, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an Array of strings called seperatedDates representing dates i.e. 13, 27, 29 I remove the comma separation using the below. Which then adds the items to the arrays indexes. i.e. 13 would be at index 0, 27 at index 1 and 29 at index 2.

```
NSArray *seperatedDates = [mayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

I then grab the current system day using

```
NSDateFormatter *dayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dayString = [dayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I cant for the life of me get my brain in gear. I assume I need to loop over the array and compare which of the array indexes is closest to todays date but ignoring todays date so for instance today is the 13th of may I would like it to grab the next closest date which would be the 27th from the array above. What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would sort your separatedDates in an temp array of NSNumber.
Then I'd look for the closest date by enumerating this temp array : actually you will look for the first date D, when D - theDateToTest < 0

When you get the date D, just get its index in the separatedDates array.